# Firebase login failed on mobile

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I have a application in unity. I can login to firebase in my pc and when I create an .exe but when I generate an apk the login failed. Should I configure anything else?

My script

```
void Start()
{
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
}

public void Login()
{
    string email = inputFieldEmail.text;
    string password = inputFieldPassword.text;

    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        GameManager.instance.SetNombre(email.Split('@')[0]);
        signedIn = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should configure on your Firebase console your mobile device keys. Also remember that Firebase is currently working with API 16+.

More information here: **https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup**

Comment: I modified my question. Should I replace method start for step 6?

Comment: try it. Step 6 works for me, if replacing this peace of code still doesn't work, check your console configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Some brief advice on that code, try replacing `ContinueWith` with [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension). This will make it easier to debug your code, and avoid any thread-related issues in Unity (in particular, your `GameManager.instance.SetNombre` makes me nervous). It's a drop in replacement.

For authentication to work on Android, you need three things:

1. a google-services.json file (there's a chance that you have a GoogleService-Info.plist if you registered an iOS app). From the [help site](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en):

> 1. Get config file for your Android app Go to your the
>    Project settings in the Firebase console.
> 2. In the Your apps card,
>    select the package name of the app for which you need a config file.
> 3. Click google-services.json.
> 4. Move your config file into the module
>    (app-level) directory of your app. Make sure that you only have this
>    most recent downloaded config file in your app.

(note for step 4 in Unity - just put it somewhere in your Assets/ directory)

2. Make sure that you've enabled analytics in your Firebase console. It sounds like you've done this already.
3. Add your SHA-1 to Firebase. This is based on signing key, so each developer may need to register their local development SHA-1, and you'll want to register your final signing key. From the [help site](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en):

> Follow these steps if you didn't initially provide a SHA certificate
> fingerprint for your Firebase Android app or if you need to add an
> additional one.
>
> 1. Make sure that you have the SHA fingerprint of your signing
>    certificate.
> 2. In your Project settings, go to the Your apps card.
> 3. Select the Firebase Android app to which you want to add a SHA
>    fingerprint.
> 4. Click Add fingerprint.
> 5. Enter or paste the SHA
>    fingerprint, then click Save.

To [get your development SHA-1 key](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth), enter roughly this command:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

And if you can't run the keytool command, I wrote [this brief explainer](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/whats-keytool-why-can-t-it-be-found-and-why-does-firebase-even-want-a-sha-1-a3f568867a7b). You can find it in your JDK directory (you have a JDK somewhere if you're making Android builds).